# replacingOccurrences with string from array

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am making a application which will "fill in the blanks" in a uilabel.text
from a text file. I am kinda stuck on how to populate my text file with the array of words **chosenWords** String type. so far I am able to display the text and replace the "blanks" in my text file , with just a single word but I can't figure out how to use my chosenWords array to replace the §§§ in the text file with words from it. anyone able to help me out?

```
class GameVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var storyLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        if let Path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "fortelling1", withExtension: "rtf") {
            do {
                let attributedStringWithRtf: NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(url: Path, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
                self.storyLabel.attributedText = attributedStringWithRtf
                self.storyLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT",
                                              size: 30.0)

                storyLabel.text = storyLabel.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "§§§", with: "YES")

            } catch let error {
                print("Got an error \(error)")
            }
        }


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are 9/10 of the way there. You need to loop, looking to see what the range of the substring "§§§" is and, if it is there, replacing that range with the next item in the list.

For example:

```
var s = "The Pep Boys are §§§, §§§, and §§§."
var arr = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"]
while let r = s.range(of:"§§§") {
    s.replaceSubrange(r, with: arr.removeFirst())
}
// The Pep Boys are Manny, Moe, and Jack.
```

Of course this assumes none of the strings in `arr` contains or generates a new occurrence of `"§§§"`, but I think we *can* assume that for purposes of simplicity. Also there's some deliberate inefficiency in my implementation, which would be objectionable if the target string were very long, but again, for pedagogical purposes I think it's best to keep it simple for now.